# Why the code doesn't compile

Tags: c#

Why the code doesn't compile, when it's doing the same thing.

Error message:

> Cannot convert from System.Action to System.Threading.ThreadStart.

Code:

```
// Compiles and works
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() => {
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(100); Interlocked.Increment(ref Count);
    });
    t.Start();
}

// doesn't compile
Action action = () => {
    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    Interlocked.Increment(ref Count);
};

for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(action);
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Cannot convert from System.Action to System.Threading.ThreadStart, but isnt the first one doing the same thing

Comment: What I am asking is, why wont the compiler know that it has the same signature, that is it doesnt take any parameters and doesnt return anything.  Wont it do it implicitly like the previous one

Comment: @user1712323, please edit your question to include the error message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because there is an implicit conversion to a `ThreadStart` delegate from a lambda with the correct signature, but not from an `Action` delegate to a `ThreadStart` delegate. An explicit conversion exists, though:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(action));
```

A lambda expression doesn't have a type, but it's compatible with any delegate with matching parameters and return type. Delegate types, on the other hand, are not implicitly convertible to each other, but can be explicitly converted if they have compatible signatures.

Comment: Thanks, the last comment makes sense. Appreciate it.